# NAudio MeteringSampleProvider not firing events?

Tags: c#, .net, audio, naudio, wave

From all the samples I've seen using NAudio's MeteringSampleProvider to update a VolumeMeter control, I think I've got the right code, but it seems that the event for the MeteringSampleProvider as well as the SampleChannel never fire.  I'm writing to a wav file at the same time and when I play it back, the recording has worked fine.  Any ideas?

```
IWaveIn wavStream;
WaveFileWriter wavWriter;
BufferedWaveProvider bufferedWaveProvider;
SampleChannel sampleChannel;
MeteringSampleProvider meteringSampleProvider;

wavStream = new WaveIn();
wavWriter = new WaveFileWriter(CurrentRecording.Filename, wavStream.WaveFormat);

wavStream.DataAvailable += new EventHandler<WaveInEventArgs>((s2, e2) =>
{
  //Add sample to the buffered provider
  bufferedWaveProvider.AddSamples(e2.Buffer, 0, e2.BytesRecorded);

  //************************************************************
  //EDIT: This is how I solved the issue!!!      
  var tmpBuffer = new float[e2.BytesRecorded];
  if (meteringSampleProvider != null)
    meteringSampleProvider.Read(tmpBuffer, 0, e2.BytesRecorded);
  //END EDIT
  //************************************************************

  //Write to the wave file
  wavWriter.Write(e2.Buffer, 0, e2.BytesRecorded);  
});

//Create our Buffered provider
bufferedWaveProvider = new BufferedWaveProvider(wavStream.WaveFormat);
bufferedWaveProvider.DiscardOnBufferOverflow = true;

//Create the sample channel
sampleChannel = new SampleChannel(bufferedWaveProvider);
sampleChannel.PreVolumeMeter += new EventHandler<StreamVolumeEventArgs>((s2, e2) =>
{
  Console.WriteLine("PreVolumeMeter");
});

//Create the metering sample provider
meteringSampleProvider = new MeteringSampleProvider(sampleChannel);
meteringSampleProvider.StreamVolume += new EventHandler<StreamVolumeEventArgs>((s2, e2) =>
{
  Console.WriteLine("PostVolumeMeter");
});


//Start Recording
wavStream.StartRecording();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not reading from the `meteringSampleProvider`, so no events will be raised. Normally of course this would be the `IWavePlayer` that is calling `Read`, but if you are not playing audio, you'll need to pull the audio through your pipeline some other way.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to do this?  I just want to grab the metering info on the WaveIn()...  I can't seem to find a way to do this in any samples (they all show metering from a WaveFileReader)

Comment: So my solution was to simply call .Read on my MeteringSampleProvider right after I added a sample to it, in the DataAvailable callback on the original WaveIn Stream.  This way I always read out the exact data that was put into the sample provider, and it causes my events to fire.  The data just goes into a buffer that's never used, so it may not be the best way, but it works!  Thanks for your help!